Accessing SharePoint Files via API Results in 'AudienceUriValidationFailedException'
I have used all the correct values in the following code, and I am successfully receiving an access token:
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"

payload = {
"client_id": "CLIENT-ID",
"client_secret": "CLIENT-SECRET",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" 
}

I have given it all the possible amount of API permission (for testing purposes ofcourse)
but when I access it through the REST API below:
(I have a site called TestSite, and a folder called Guide)
https://{site_url}.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/Guide')/Files

I keep getting the error 401 'error_description': "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown.
Why is it like this? Can anyone please help me with this issue?
I have tried everything there is, but I still can't find a solution to access the SharePoint files from the API

Please edit your question and add more details like your current complete code instead of images.

Hi @Sridevi, I have edited and updated the question.

The error occurred as you generated token for Microsoft Graph but using it for SharePoint API. As you generated MS Graph token, use MS Graph API calls to fetch SharePoint sites information.

You can also decode the access token by pasting it in https://jwt.ms website and check aud and roles claim values.

checked the access token on jwt,ms, looks fine to me. But, how do you mean to change the use MS Graph API calls to fetch SharePoint? Can you please give an example?

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to retrieve files present in Guide folder of TestSite sharepoint site via API in python?

I also tried with the scope: "https://sharepoint.com/.default" and "https://.sharepoint.com/.default" and it still gives the same error

Yes, my requirement is to retrieve files present in Guide folder of TestSite sharepoint site via API in python

Okay will post the answer with example code to retrieve files present in Guide folder of TestSite sharepoint site using Graph API in some time

I created one folder named Guide in "TestSite" SharePoint site and uploaded below files in it:

To access SharePoint files present in site folder via Graph API, you can make use of below API call:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteId>/drives/<driveId>/root:/Guide:/children

To get the values of siteId and driveId, you can run below Graph API calls:
Site ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/TestSite


Drive ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drives?$filter=name eq 'Documents'


Now, I ran below sample code and got the response successfully with SharePoint files like this:
import requests

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"
scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

payload = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": scope,
}

try:
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    token_data = response.json()
    access_token = token_data.get("access_token")


    api_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root:/Guide:/children"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    api_response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    if api_response.status_code == 200:
        files = api_response.json().get("value", [])
        for file in files:
            print(f"File Name: {file['name']}, ID: {file['id']}")
    else:
        print(f"API Call Failed: {api_response.status_code}, {api_response.text}")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Response:


Thank you for the detailed response, really appreciate it!
When I use the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drives?$filter=name eq 'Documents' (with my site id that I got), I receive an empty values list ("value": []), whereas in your example you have received a list of values. Why is it like that?

Try filtering with 'Shared Documents'. Or you can also query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drives and get drive ID of Shared Documents

Still nothing. Is it possible that I don't have a drive or something else that's causing this issue?

What response you are getting when you run GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drives ? Could you add that image here?

Wasn't able to upload a picture in the comment section, sorry for that, so here is a link to the picture https://ibb.co/rwGh3Zp

Additionally, share image links of site ID retrieval and SharePoint portal image having path of drive

Here is the image url for site ID retrieval https://ibb.co/WP0GmJ7, and here is the SharePoint portal image URL https://ibb.co/njq4tm7
There was no drive path here it seems

Click on Guide folder and share the image link so that we can check address bar for files path

Here is the image URL for the guide folder https://ibb.co/FBvt8vc

Everything seems fine only for me. Could you confirm whether the signed-in user of SharePoint Portal and Graph Explorer are same or not?

They are the same, yes

In my case GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drive also worked. Check this https://i.imgur.com/LeBYINw.png

Have you added consent to Files.Read.All permission?

Let me check that again, wait

You mean these permissions right? https://i.sstatic.net/TM2EiAgJ.png

You granted permissions in app registration. While running queries in Graph Explorer, make sure to grant consent to permissions here https://i.imgur.com/D4VOjKW.png

I'm not able to allow consent on that, does that mean that is the main issue because of which I'm not able to access files Sharepoint files through API?

Most probably that's the issue. Alternatively, run python code by replacing api url with GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteIdfromAbove/drives and check whether you are getting any response or not as code works on app registration's permissions.

@MuhammadArsal Any update?

My apologies; I didn't see your reply, but yes, your answer was the solution, and with it, I solved my problem/issue. Thank you!
